# Android - как получить IP-адрес устройства?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Появился вопрос: как получить IP-адрес девайса не в локальной сети (т.е. я хочу получить 90.356.174.278, а не 192.168.1.9) с API < 9? Гугл выдаёт только код для получение адреса в локальной сети или предлагает мне юзать API >= 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces()) и [`NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getInetAddresses()) доступны с API 1.

[Пример использования.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device)

Comment: То, что надо! Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Просто отправить запрос на http://api.ipify.org
Можно запросить http://api.ipify.org?format=json или http://api.ipify.org?format=xml, чтобы получить ответ в json или xml

Answer (score 0):

Открыть соответствующий сервис, например http://checkip.org/ и отпарсить страничку, а точнее найти строку содержащую "Your IP address:" и обработать её.

Comment: А можно попроще? Или проще некуда?

Comment: По моему, проще некуда. Воспользуйся HttpClient андроидским.

Comment: Гм. Зачем парсить HTML какого-то сервиса? Если уж так хочется что-то парсить, то ведь есть `ipconfig`.

Comment: @falstaf, а разве в `ifconfig` (или функции, возвращающей IP интерфейса) будет IP *после* NAT на роутере?